# Custom Block within catalog/product_view doesn't show up

Tags: magento

I want to modify the content that shows up on my Magento website's product view page and I want to create my own custom block for use on the page as well.

## What I've Done

### Create Layout Updates For Product View Handle

To update what was displayed on the product's view page, I put the following
layout updates within my `local.xml` file:

```xml
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <remove name="product.tierprices" />
        <remove name="product.info.upsell" />
        <remove name="product.clone_prices" />
        <remove name="product.description" />
        <remove name="product.tag.list" />
        <remove name="product.info.addto" />
        <remove name="product.info.addtocart" />
        <remove name="product.info.downloadcontent" />
        <remove name="product.info.extrahint" />
        <remove name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" />
        <remove name="product.info.container1" />
        <remove name="product.info.container2" />
        <remove name="alert.urls" />
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
        <remove name="cart_sidebar" />
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout" />
        <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo" />
        <remove name="right.poll" />
        <remove name="bundle.tierprices" />
        <remove name="product.attributes" />

        <!-- This should override the original product.info block -->
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <!-- Custom MyNamespace_Videos_Block_Player block -->
            <block type="videos/player" name="videoPlayer" as="videoPlayer" template="video/player.phtml"/>
        </block>

    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

At this point, I confirmed the remove nodes worked. Obviously, because I hadn't
created the `videos/player` block class at this point, nothing showed up.

### Custom Module

I created a custom module by creating the following folder structure under `app/code/local`:

- MyNameSpace
- MyNameSpace/Videos
- MyNameSpace/Videos/Block
- MyNameSpace/Videos/etc

I created the config file for the module at `MyNameSpace/Videos/etc/config.xml` and placed the following xml nodes within:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <mynamespace_videos>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </mynamespace_videos>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <videos>
                <class>MyNamespace_Videos_Block</class>
            </videos>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

I then enabled the module and verified that it worked.

### Custom Block Class

I've created a custom block within `MyNameSpace/Videos/Block/Player.phtml` with the following:

```php
class MyNamespace_Videos_Block_Player extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
    public function _toHtml() {
        echo "Block's _toHtml() method called!";
        parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

### Custom Template File

I then created the custom template file at `design/frontend/mythemepackage/default/template/video/player.phtml` that contains the following:

```php
<!--Check to see if Magento sees this!-->
<?php Mage::log(get_class($this)); ?>
```

### Modified catalog/product/view.phtml

To have my `videos/player` block show up within `catalog/product/view.phtml`, I
copied `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` to
my design package at
`app/design/frontend/mythemepackage/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`.

I then added the following line to the newly copied view template:

```php
<b>This text will show up!</b>
<i>The following wont: </i>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('videoPlayer'); ?>
```

## Outcome

With the above configuration, I cannot get the `videoPlayer` block to render.

Here's what I know:

- I *can* see the normal html text in my `catalog/product/view.phtml` file.
   I cannot see what is echoed from `$this->getChildHtml('videoPlayer');`
- The `_toHtml()` method of `MyNamespace_Videos_Block_Player` class is *not*
   being called and I cannot see any output from my `video/player.phtml` template.
- If I copy `catalog.xml` from
   `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml` to
   `app/design/frontend/mythemepackage/default/layout/catalog.xml` and then add
   my `videos/player` block to it, I *can* see "Block's _toHtml() method called!"
   that has been echoed by the `videos/player` block. The following is what
   the addition to `catalog.xml` looks like:

```xml
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
        <block type="videos/player" name="videoPlayer" as="videoPlayer" template="video/player.phtml"/>
    </block>
```

- Even though using a local version of `catalog.xml` calls my block's `_toHtml()` method, nothing is output from my template.

## Questions

I've spent quite a while doing troubleshooting for this. I've deleted the cache completely at `var/cache` and verified that the module is active and is working.

- What am I missing? What needs to happen to get the block to render?
- Why does copying `catalog.xml` and adding my block there work but updating
   through `local.xml` doesn't?

Comment: this is a pretty long question... you might want to consider narrowing it down a bit

Comment: I actually just figured out what the issue was. I had nested my <catalog_product_view> handle within the <default> handle on accident within my local.xml file. Now it works. Should I delete my question?

Comment: oh, okay, you should delete it then.

Comment: Having fun with layout XML? :-)

Because `<remove />` uses block names in layout, it is not necessary/appropriate to nest `<remove />` directives in anything other layout update handles. If you want to break parent-child relationships (remove a block from a parent but leave it available for use) then you should use `<acton method="unsetChild"><block>alias</block></action>` in the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you can add  `<catalog_product_view>` tag in your module `layout xml`

```
<catalog_product_view>
     <reference name="content">
         <reference name="product.info">
             <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                 <block type="videos/player" name="videoPlayer" as="videoPlayer" template="video/player.phtml"/>
             </block> 
         </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

This will be help you